# What does "¿Que es eso?" mean?

Tags: pronombres, acentuación, pronombre-interrogativo

Sometimes I see "¿Que es eso?" when watching Spanish films. Is it a missprint of "¿Qué es eso?" where they have forgotten the acute on the *e* or does it mean something else?

Comment: Just to confirm that both have the same meaning: "What is that?". The use of "Que" in a interrogation without acute is wrong. Look at the answer of DGaleano here http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16676/8972

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Should be `Qué` instead of `Que`.

Comment: It means cheese.  They want someone to smile at the camera.  (I'm being silly here, cheese is spelled queso ;-).

Comment: @DGaleano. No, look for example: Two friends meet, one of them is carrying a very heavy object - Carlos, eso que estas cargando. ¿Es un computador? - No exactamente, ¿sabes que los equipos de transmisión de electricidad a veces necesitan conectarse a un dispositivo para diagnosticar si están funcionando correctamente? - ¿Que es eso? - Si, sirve para hacer pruebas. Lo llevo a la central eléctrica.

Comment: Whenever there is the word `que` without tilde, it means there must be something first. Example: `¿Que es eso?` -> `¿Así que es eso?` -> `So it is that?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The words **qué, cuál/es, quién/es, cómo, cuán, cuánto/a/os/as, cuándo, dónde y adónde** are written with acute accent (tilde diacrítica) when used in an interrogative or exclamatory manner.

You can read this in [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde),

There is no difference in meaning but when you see any of those words in a question without the accent, it is wrong.

Comment: Nótese que hay una respuesta de bns que ha sido convertida a [comentario](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16675/what-does-que-es-eso-mean#comment21091_16675). Ella pretendía responder a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 8):

I'll be the contrarian here.

*¿que es eso?* is a valid Spanish construction and distinct from *¿qué es eso?*

With the accent, the phrase means "What is that?" because *qué* is an interrogative pronoun.  But without the accent, the phrase means something more akin to "You mean it's *that*?"  The word *que* (no accent) is often used in spoken Spanish to start off phrases without entirely too much rhyme or reason except perhaps to give a stronger link to the previous statement (cf. *pues*), not unlike English's *so*.

For example, imagine someone has just described you a person, and someone comes walking around the corner and you think it's that person, but you're a bit incredulous.  You'd say, *¿Que es él/ella?* and your friend would respond *sí/no*.  If you asked *¿qué es él/ella* your friend would just say *pues, un ser humano* :-)  You actually can hear the difference in speech.  Without the accent, there are only two stressed syllables and more likely than not, only three syllables in total /'que'se.so/.  With the accent, there are three stressed syllables and four total /'que'es'eso/

Now, that all being said, ***¿qué es eso?* is going to be *vastly* more common than *¿que es eso?***, and so it's probably just a typo.

Comment: I always learn from your answers @guifa but I have to ask this. In your /'que'se.so/ example I would say you are not making a real question even if the structure of the sentence looks like a question, so I'd think it could be written like **¡qué es eso!** instead of using question marks. If this is correct, this would be an exclamatory sentence and then again according to RAE it would have to have the accent. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @guifa: I think you are right: if there is an ellipsis at the beginning of the sentence, something like "¿[Dices] que es eso?" or "¿[Me estás diciendo] que es él/ella?", in these cases, **que** would the be a relative pronoun and wouldn't be accented.

Comment: In the unaccented version, 'que' would be more akin to 'that' than 'what'. I also want to chime in that, as a native speaker, it's incredibly common to see this gaffe, still wrong, though.

Answer (score 3):

Should be "¿**Qué** es eso?", with an acute accent, as explained in [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=qu%C3%A9):

> Qué: Palabra tónica, que debe escribirse con tilde a diferencia del pronombre relativo o de la conjunción que.